# How can I bring my app in front after lost the front position?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Let's say my app is doing some work and it takes some good seconds to finish it. Meanwhile, the user of my app starts working with another app. But the work is happening in my app and it is finished now. How can I bring my app to the front in order to inform the user the job is finished?

Comment: Definitely do not bring your app back to the front. Nothing would be more annoying to the user than to have their work in some other app interrupted by another app forcing itself into the front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these cases we usually show a [User Notification](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/scheduling-local-notifications) to inform user that their task is complete.

But if you want to bring your window to the front, you could just use:

```
NSApp.mainWindow?.orderFrontRegardless()
```

Or if your app is in Menubar (hidden from Dock) and you want to display the main window:

```
NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
openWindow(id: YOUR_WINDOW_ID)
NSApp.mainWindow?.orderFrontRegardless()
```

Comment: @HelloCodes Regarding `openWindow()` you define it on top of your SwiftUI view: `Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow` and the ID is just the id you assign to your window in your `Scene`. Did you check the link for User Notification I had in my answer? even though I tried to answer what you want to do, using User Notifications is the standard way of notifying the user in these situations (basically a small box appears on the top right corner notifying the user that the task is complete)